# how to prevent opening serial port on linux by foreign application?

Tags: linux, locking, serial-port

In case of "bug" in port driver using locking is not acceptable.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Are you writing the serial driver? What do you mean by "foreign"?

Comment: Yes, it's programming question. No, I'm writing application for device connected via serial port with buggy driver. Foreign - started from any other binaries.

Comment: See: [What is the best practice for locking serial ports and other devices in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316722/what-is-the-best-practice-for-locking-serial-ports-and-other-devices-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

So you need to lock out other processes from opening a device file, but file locking is unacceptable...

Well, you could rename the device file to something non-standard, so everything that tries to open /dev/ttyS0 won't step on your toes.

Comment: *THANKS*. It's interested idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are guarding against *mistaken* opens by "foreign" binaries: in your driver's open() method, match the name of the opening binary (current->comm).  And allow opens only for your binary.

This can, of course be easily circumvented (by renaming a foreign binary.)

Comment: *THANKS*

It's interested but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change the properties of the corresponding dev file, only granting access to a custom group you are a member of. If you want the serial port to be accessible to any user, this might not work.